# MySql backup and restore over ssh Lost connection error

Tags: mysql, ssh, pipe, backup, restore

I usually get a local copy of a big MySql remote production  database on Debian with the following command:

```
ssh user@remotehost.it "mysqldump -u user -ppassword  --single-transaction --databases  db1 db2 " | pv -t -b -r -W | mysql -u user -ppassword
```

It take some hours so I can see the pipe status with the `pv` (pipe view) command.

A month ago after 3 hours and 6 Gb the process stopped with the error

```
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the `pv`, the command [pipe view](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) that a buffer of 400-500 kb that was completely full.

I modified the command with a greater buffer size:

```
ssh user@remotehost.it "mysqldump -u user -ppassword  --single-transaction --databases  db1 db2 " | pv -pterbWTCB 1G | mysql -u user -ppassword
```